# How can I read data from a json file, do I have a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, web-applications

I'm starting angularJS and I want to learn how to read from a json file but I can't figure out where the problem in my code is

So I'm trying to display data from my json file into my view inside a

tag but its showing blank space.

app.js :

```
    //Routing
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
      controller: 'myController'
    })
    // some routing
    //some more routing

    ;

}]);
//Routing end


myApp.controller('myController',function($scope, $http){

  $http.get("data/users.json").then(function(response){
      $scope.users = response.data;
    });

});
```

view1.html:

```
    <div class="content">
  <h1 class="princip">Reparation</h1>
  <hr>
  

  <div>
    <p>user: {{user.name}} </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

users.json:

```
[{
    "name": "yoshi",
    "code": "black",
    "id": 101,
}, {
    "name": "minato",
    "code": "orange",
    "id": 102,
}]
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app ="myApp">
  <head>

    <script src="class\class.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app\lib\angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="app\app.js"></script>



    <title>Wellcome !</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
    <div ng-include="'sidebar.html'"></div>
    <main ng-view=""></main>
  </body>
</html>
```

My file system:

```
-Project
  index.html
  -app
    app.js
  -data
    users.json
  -views
    view1.html
```

is there a syntax error ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $scope.users is getting an array of users, enclosed by []

So your {{user.username}} must understand somehow that it's getting one of the array elements. I would expect some sort of iteration here over the array, so {{user}} can be understood as an item from $scope.users.

Another thing is that the first user in the array has an attribute called name, while the second one has an attribute called username, so only the 2nd one will work (for the 1st one, your code will assume the user.username value is null).

Comment: i think that is the problem I don't want to pass an array to $scope.users (I should change the name to $scope.user) I want to pass just one user which then I can display its data.